# Select closest element to button in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="name">Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>ZIP</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="GetElement(this)">Get Element</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="name">Name2</td>
        <td>Surname2</td>
        <td>Date2</td>
        <td>City2</td>
        <td>ZIP2</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="GetElement(this)">Get Element</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

By clicking the anchor link, I want to get the first, third and forth `<td>`.
I'm trying to do it by jQuery using `closest()`, but I'm getting undefined. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function GetElement(e){
    var elem = $(e).closest("#name").text();
    console.log(elem);
}
```

Comment: Please update question with code that you have tried, even if not working.

Comment: @Yogi updated it. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

`closest` does work. You are not targeting the right element though. Get the `tr` instead (`#name` is not a parent of the `a` element, thus the `undefined`). You can then get the children with `find()` :

```js
function GetElement(link) {
  $(link).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(4)').addClass('red');
}
```

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>City</td>
      <td>ZIP</td>
      <td><a onclick="GetElement(this)">Get Element</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td>Surname2</td>
      <td>Date2</td>
      <td>City2</td>
      <td>ZIP2</td>
      <td><a onclick="GetElement(this)">Get Element</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: jQuery closest will not select sibling elements, correct?   The documentation was not clear to me. +1

Comment: `closest` tries to find the first parent DOM element that matches the selector provided as parameter